# How to avoid StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: java, exception, selenium

```
   public long SearchHotel(String hotelname,String Provider,String CookieName) throws InterruptedException, ParseException{
    long Day = 0;
    WebDriver driver =new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    driver.get("url");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.id("hc_f_id_where_1")).sendKeys(hotelname);
    List<WebElement> HL = driver.findElements(By.id("ui-id-1"));
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.id("ui-id-1")));
    String startDate = null;
    String endDate = null;
    Date d1,d2;
    Calendar firstDate =null;
    Calendar secondDate =null;
    org.joda.time.DateTime dt1;
    org.joda.time.DateTime dt2;
    long diffInMillisec=0;
    long diffInDays=0;

    //DateTime dt2;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = null;
    for (WebElement e : HL) 
    {
        if(e.getText().contains(hotelname))
        {
            System.out.println("In IF");
            driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText(hotelname)).click();
        }           
    }

    driver.findElement(By.id("HC_DateSelection_checkin_1")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.ui-datepicker-trigger")).click();
    WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.ui-datepicker-group.ui-datepicker-group-last table.ui-datepicker-calendar"));
    List<WebElement> columns=dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("td")); 

    for (WebElement cell : columns)
    {
        //System.out.println(cell.getText());
        if(cell.getText().equals("7"))
        {
            cell.findElement(By.linkText("7")).click();
            break;
        }
    }


    driver.findElement(By.id("HC_DateSelection_checkout_1")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#HC_DateSelection_checkout_1 img.ui-datepicker-trigger")).click();

    WebElement datewidget1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.ui-datepicker-group.ui-datepicker-group-first table.ui-datepicker-calendar"));
    List<WebElement> columns1 = datewidget1.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    for (WebElement cell1 : columns1)
    {
        //System.out.println(cell1.getText());
        if(cell1.getText().equals("11"))
        {
            cell1.findElement(By.linkText("11")).click();
            break;
        }
    }   

    driver.findElement(By.className("hc_f_btn_v15")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.className("hc_usi")).click();

    System.out.println("Waiting");
    WebElement HotelList=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table#hc_htl_pm_rates_content"));
    List<WebElement> Hl=HotelList.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));


    for (WebElement H : Hl) {

        if(Provider.equals(H.getAttribute("data-providername"))){


            System.out.println("Provider Name : "+H.getAttribute("data-providername").toString());

            Wait<WebDriver> fwait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);
            fwait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(H.findElement(By.tagName("a")))).click();

            H.findElement(By.tagName("a")).click();
            break;

        }

    }

    Set<String> winHandles=driver.getWindowHandles();
    for (String window : winHandles) 
        {
            driver.switchTo().window(window);   
        }


    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.tagName("h1")));
    System.out.println("Page Title : "+driver.getTitle());
    String curURL=driver.getCurrentUrl();
    System.out.println("Current URL : "+curURL);
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Set<Cookie> cookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
      Iterator<Cookie> itr = cookies.iterator();
      while (itr.hasNext())
         {
             Cookie c = itr.next();
             System.out.println("-----Cookies Detail-----");
             System.out.println("Cookie Name: " + c.getName()  + "\n\tCookie Domain: " + c.getDomain() +  "\n\tCookie Value: " + c.getValue() +  "\n\tPath: " + c.getPath()+  "\n\tExpiry Date: " + c.getExpiry()+  "\n\tSecure: " + c.isSecure());


             if(CookieName.equalsIgnoreCase(c.getName()))
                {
                 System.out.println("Cookies Found : " +CookieName);
                 try
                    {
                        endDate = c.getExpiry().toString();
                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm:ss Z yyyy");
                        //SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                        d1=format.parse(endDate);
                        System.out.println(d1);
                        d2=new Date();
                        startDate=d2.toString();

                        d2=format.parse(startDate);

                        System.out.println(d2);

                        dt1 = new org.joda.time.DateTime(d1);
                        dt2 = new org.joda.time.DateTime(d2);

                        Day=Days.daysBetween(dt2,dt1).getDays();

                    firstDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                        secondDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                        firstDate.setTime(d1);
                        secondDate.setTime(d2);
                        int month = firstDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
                        int dt = firstDate.get(Calendar.DATE);
                        int year = firstDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                        firstDate.set(year, month, dt);

                        System.out.println("First Dare "+dt+"/"+month+"/"+year);

                        int month2=secondDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
                        int dt22 = secondDate.get(Calendar.DATE);
                        int year2= secondDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                        secondDate.set(year2, month2, dt22);
                        System.out.println("Second Date "+dt22+"/"+month2+"/"+year2);

                        diffInMillisec = firstDate.getTimeInMillis() - secondDate.getTimeInMillis(); 
                        diffInDays = diffInMillisec / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                        System.out.println("DAYS : "+diffInDays);


                     }
                 catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

         }
      driver.quit();
      return diffInDays;
```

}

getting Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Command duration or timeout: 5.50 seconds

Comment: what line is failing?

Comment: failing at - WebElement HotelList=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table#hc_htl_pm_rates_content"));